# How to design network layer with refresh token request?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-mvp

So I currently face the situation when a logged in user token expires and for any of his requests to succeed refresh token call needs to be performed first. how should I design my requests.

`//Network Calls
Observable<UserResponse> login(/*params*/);
Observable<RefreshTokenResponse> refreshToken(/*params*/);
Observable<GetAddressListResponse> getAddressList(/*params*/)`

Answer (score 0):

Recently I developed the library that suits your needs.

[RetrofitRxErrorHandler](https://github.com/RobertZagorski/RetrofitRxErrorHandler)

If you combine `Simple` strategy reacting to HTTP error code with backup `Observable` you will get the expected result.

However it is for RxJava 1. You are welcome to improve it and align it to RxJava 2.